# What is the right way to make a class outside main.cpp to use QtQuick2ApplicationViewer?

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt5, qtquick2

I want to make a C++ application that uses QML for dialog UI.

I am trying to put my UI code outside ***main.cpp***, so that I can later separate it to run in a thread.

I build & run: No errors in compilation, no errors in application output.

However, nothing shows up on the screen. But if written in *main.cpp*, this chunk of code shows the QML dialog correctly:

```
QtQuick2ApplicationViewer viewer;
viewer.setMainQmlFile(QStringLiteral("qml/Kiosk/main.qml"));

viewer.showExpanded();
```

What I do:

*New Project -> Applications -> Qt Quick 2 Application (Built-in Elements)*

I leave *main.qml* as it is.

I add a new class "Dialog"

*Dialog.h* code:

```
#ifndef DIALOG_H
#define DIALOG_H

#include <QObject>

#include "qtquick2applicationviewer.h"

class Dialog : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Dialog(QObject *parent = 0);

    void show();

    signals:

public slots:

};

#endif // DIALOG_H
```

*Dialog.cpp* code:

```
#include "dialog.h"

Dialog::Dialog(QObject *parent) :
    QObject(parent)
{    
}

void Dialog::show()
{
    QtQuick2ApplicationViewer viewer;
    viewer.setMainQmlFile(QStringLiteral("qml/Kiosk/main.qml"));

    viewer.showExpanded();
}
```

*main.cpp* code:

```
#include <QtGui/QGuiApplication>    
#include "dialog.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    Dialog *dia = new Dialog();
    dia->show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

When I switch back to *QtQuick 1.0* and replace the chunk of code that uses ***QtQuick2ApplicationViewer*** with ***QDeclarativeView*** :

```
view = new QDeclarativeView();
view->rootContext()->setContextProperty("Dialog", this);    //this
view->setSource(QUrl("qml/Kiosk/main.qml"));
view->setResizeMode(QDeclarativeView::SizeRootObjectToView);
```

my QML app displays correctly. But I want to use ***QtQuick 2.0***. I am new to Qt programming, so any help would be highly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You are doing it the wrong way. You don't simply open different qml viewers as different widgets. Your dialog needs to be merely a QML element you show alongside your other QML components in the single main viewer. And for the LAST time - you don't run UI in any thread but the main thread.

Answer (score 1):

Came across this question while I was looking for resources myself. I think I can shed some light on your issues but am only just getting to grips with QtQuick myself.

in your `Dialog::Show()` method you are creating a local `QtQuick2ApplicationViewer` which will be destroyed when the function call ends and hence you won't see anything as it will return immediately.

Also the simplest way I have found to get a qml displaying is to use a QQuickView directly.
e.g.

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  QApplication app(argc, argv);

  QQuickView qtQuickApp;
  qtQuickApp.setSource(QUrl("test.qml"));
  qtQuickApp.show();


  app.connect( &app, SIGNAL( lastWindowClosed() ), &app, SLOT( quit() ) );
  app.exec();

  return 0;

} // main
```